# Attribute Table into pandas DataFrame-PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, pandas

I'm trying to develop a plugin in QGIS.

My issue is that I don't know how to **transform an attribute table into a dataframe** in order to use it further in `run(self)` function later.

I also used a comboBox in order to insert a layer the code below is located in `run` function:

```
layers=QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
self.dlg.comboBox.addItems([layer.name() for layer in layers])
selectedLayerIndex=self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
selectedLayer=layers[selectedLayerIndex].layer()
```

I used Plugin Builder and Qt Designer.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following code to make the conversion. I make a conversion to a pandas `DataFrame` and then to a geopandas `GeoDataFrame`. You may use only first part of the recipe

You can also note that I do not cast each column to pandas `dtype` completely at the end of the script e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197774/assign-pandas-dataframe-column-dtypes. To get QGIS column types (human readable), look at unused `columns_types` in the code. The code to convert from `Dataframe` to `GeoDataFrame` is mainly borrowed from official GeoPandas doc section about [Creating a GeoDataFrame from WKT format](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html#From-WKT-format)

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
from shapely import wkt

layer = layers[selectedLayerIndex].layer()
# for standalone case, comment above and uncomment below
# layer = iface.activeLayer()

columns = [f.name() for f in layer.fields()] + ['geometry']
columns_types = [f.typeName() for f in layer.fields()] # We exclude the geometry. Human readable
# or
# columns_types = [f.type() for f in layer.fields()] # QVariant type
row_list = []
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    row_list.append(dict(zip(columns, f.attributes() + [f.geometry().asWkt()])))

df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=columns)
df['geometry'] = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['geometry'])
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
gdf = gdf.set_crs(crs=layer.crs().toWkt())
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!

Comment: Accept it as an answer plz https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_ak_riks')[0]

#List all columns you want to include in the dataframe. I include all with:
cols = [f.name() for f in lyr.fields()] #Or list them manually: ['kommunnamn', 'kkod', ... ]

#A generator to yield one row at a time
datagen = ([f[col] for col in cols] for f in lyr.getFeatures())

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=datagen, columns=cols)
```

[image]